# mySQL get row twice if field = this

Tags: mysql

I'm pulling a list of names from a mySQL table called `users` with the layout something like this;

```
id   name     anon
--------------------------------
1    Roger    0
2    Craig    1
3    LOL      0
```

For users where `anon=1` I want to pull them twice, so the records I'd get from the above table would be 4 instead of 3:

```
1) Roger
2) Craig
3) Craig
4) LOL
```

I can imagine there's an easy way to do this but I'm getting brain block. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a

```
Select name from users
union all 
select name from users where anon = 1
```

and order them by name if desired?